# Need a real time, automatic, background compiler and test runner for C# .Net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, tdd, testdriven.net, test-runner

I have googled around and played around with test scripts (powershell/spec/nunit/msbuild). I am looking for a test runner that will monitor my code and will continuously rebuild and rerun all my tests for a solution. Currently I am using Resharper which has real-time compile analysis of my code, the resharper test runner and test driven .Net. 
If the solution automatically compiled, ran my tests and gave a report with a red/green dot (maybe even give me a report with hyperlinks) this would be ideal.

Edit:
I have found exactly what I was looking for: the tool I found that does exactly what I want it to do:http://www.ncrunch.net/
This is not an ad.

Also, TestDriven .Net with a shortcut (cntrl+shift+q) works pretty well.

Comment: The add-in doesn't exist as of today - July 2011. The best you can do today is setup Nunit to auto run tests when build succeeds.

Comment: I have created a build script that I run in a console window manually (builds and runs tests in 5-10 seconds depending on solution size). I guess that I could put the script together with a filesystem watcher. I just wish there was a well-tested tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

James Avery set up something like this a while ago: http://averyblog.com/net/announcing-autotest-net-0-1/

Looks like the google code project is still around.

Answer (score 13):

[NCrunch](http://www.ncrunch.net/) is starting to look very promising.

Comment: I can recommend NCrunch as well. With it latest release you get an instant info about long running code (threshold can be set to your needs)

Answer (score 0):

Such tool is called build server and regular commits (for example with distributed source control).

I wonder if you have ever seen this work in VS directly somewhere? Once VS starts compilation or test run, it is dead so you cannot work until it is done (sometimes for several minutes if the build and test contains whole solution). Background process also doesn't look like a solution because it can cause locking files (unless shadow copying is used which can result in other problems).

Comment: If there is such as serious problem with locking of files when performing a background compilation, then how does Resharper's solution-wide analysis perform background error analysis without inconveniencing me? Maybe you are right and I simply am not bothered so much.

Comment: @Kaizen: I'm really not able to answer your question with Resharper. I don't know how it works but code analysis is not the same as build itself.

Comment: I also find odd the idea commiting what is uncompleted code for the purpose of running my unit tests. I should mention that the context for rerunning all these tests all the time is refactoring. Some quite radical in the cases of design patterns and inverting control. I accept that perhaps no such product exists... yet

Comment: That was the reason why I mentioned distributed source control because it will allow you to have your own repository but you will probably have run build server localy.

Comment: I wish I could make that decision (git is awesome at home). Then I see your point.